# Java: Shall we use Local Variable for Memory or Global Variable for standard

Tags: java, global-variables, local-variables

There is clash between two developers here

One is saying that String pattern should be inside the method as it is memory friendly and not used anywhere else

```
public List<LTA> createBeanData(List<ReportData> reportDataList) throws Exception {
    String pattern = "dd-MMM-yy";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
```

The other is saying that it is kind a reusable thing and can be used in future and it is java standard.

```
private static final String pattern = "dd-MMM-yy";
public List<LTA> createBeanData(List<ReportData> reportDataList) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
```

What is more important for a program?

Comment: More important than to debate where the string should be defined, is to use java.time.

Comment: Also they're missing obvious other options, like `SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");` to save a variable, and `private static final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");`. That is, if they really want to waste their time on useless things.

Comment: @Kayaman Since SimpleDateFormat isn't thread safe, your second suggestion isn't advisable.

Comment: Wrap it in a `ThreadLocal`! I'm buying!